# Python3: How to get all the squares and cubes equal or below the number

Tags: python, python-3.x, cubes

So first this is the task that I am supposed to 
"The second coding challenge will be using a while loop to solve both conditions

Given any number called a limit we will find and print all the squares that are equal or below the limit, hence:

Given 30 your first solution will print 1, 4, 9, 16, 25

the second solution will print cubes up to the limit, therefore:

Given 30 your second solution will print 1, 8, 2"

```
reply = True
while reply == True:
    limit = input("Choose any number ")
    if limit.isnumeric():
        limit = float(limit)
        reply = False
    else:
        print("What you have entered is not a number")
        reply = True

number = 1
square = list()
cube = list()
while number > 0:
    squarenumber = number ** 2
    if squarenumber > limit:
        break
    square.append(squarenumber)
    cubenumber = number ** 3
    if cubenumber > limit:
        break
    cube.append(cubenumber)
    number = number+1

print("All the squares below or equal to",limit,"are",*square)
print("All the cubes below or equal to", limit,"are",*cube)
```

This is the code that I made and when I put 30 as the value of "limit" it says

```
All the squares below or equal to 30.0 are 1 4 9 16
All the cubes below or equal to 30.0 are 1 8 27
```

So I'm not really sure what I did wrong

Comment: `while reply == True:` - if an expression evaluates to a boolean, you shouldn't compare it `True` or `False` in the `while` statement, just just write `while reply:`

Comment: Indeed it will count as a good programming practice. The former code looks more understandable though (from a novice perspective)

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when the value of `number` becomes 4. In this case, the square is calculated and condition `14 > 30` is false (30 is `limit`). But then you move on to calculate the cube, in this case the condition `64 > 30` is true and thus the loop breaks.
Thus one way is to break the loop **only when** the square of value is greater than the limit. Or you can also invert the condition (only append the squares and cubes to the list if they are less than the limit)

```
reply = True
while reply == True:
    limit = input("Choose any number ")
    if limit.isnumeric():
        limit = float(limit)
        reply = False
    else:
        print("What you have entered is not a number")
        reply = True

number = 1
square = list()
cube = list()
while number > 0:
    squarenumber = number ** 2

    # only append the square if it is less than limit value    
    if squarenumber < limit:
        square.append(squarenumber)
    else:
        break # if the square value is greater than limit, then stop the loop
    cubenumber = number ** 3
    # only append the cube if it is less than limit value 
    if cubenumber < limit:
        cube.append(cubenumber)
    number = number+1

print("All the squares below or equal to",limit,"are",*square)
print("All the cubes below or equal to", limit,"are",*cube)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking `squarenumber` and `cubenumber` against the limit won't work since cubes grow faster than squares. A better solution is to check the next square and collect the cubes.

Here is a possible solution

```
limit = 30
number = 1
square = list()
cube = list()
while number > 0:
    squarenumber = number ** 2
    square.append(squarenumber)
    if (number+1) ** 2 > limit:
        break
    cubenumber = number ** 3
    if cubenumber < limit:
        cube.append(cubenumber)

    number = number+1

print('square: {}'.format(square)) #square: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
print('cube: {}'.format(cube)) #cube: [1, 8, 27]
```